# How to parse the string into list of tuples

Tags: python, list, parsing, input, tuples

I have a string of the format -

```
" ( (4, 4), (11, 23), (8, 2), (12, 4), (7, 9) ) "
```

What is the best way in which I will get this string into meaningful integer tuples?
Lets say `fun(s)` is a function which takes such `string` `s` as parameter and returns `list` of `tuple` `a`

Ex.

```
a = fun("( (2, 3), (1, 4) )")
print (a)
>>> [(2, 3), (1, 4)]
a[0]
>>> (2, 3)
a[0][1]
>>> 3
```

Comment: Why is this downvoted? I have taken almost all efforts (editing, formatting, typos) before putting a question.

Comment: Let me know what is missing before downvoting it.

Comment: I think it was because they thought it was too simple. However, I would disagree. I found your question through Google, and it had the right answer. I had come across `eval` in the past, but I had forgotten it and had never used it in this context, even though I have done quite a lot of Python programming recently.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use Python's built-in [eval()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval) function.

In this case, you can write your code like this:

```
s = " ( (4, 4), (11, 23), (8, 2), (12, 4), (7, 9) ) "
print(list(eval(s)))
```

Comment: Thank you! It is the right answer that I found at the right time because you had bothered to answer a question that some might have thought too obvious.

Answer (score 2):

For this kind of thing, `ast.literal_eval` is preferred to just the built-in `eval`, especially if the string is something that may come from an unknown source. The call interface is the same as `eval`:

```
print(list(ast.literal_eval(s)))
```

However, `ast.literal_eval` will guard against code insertions that may call system services (such as those that might delete files, etc.), and only accept literal values.

Comment: Thank you. Security is not an issue in my case, but it is good to know about it.